# Determining android play store

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I have written the following code in my Android app to determine which play store it is downlaoded from :

```
public enum AppStore {
        GOOGLE("com.android.vending", "market://details?id="), 
        AMAZON("com.amazon.venezia", "amzn://apps/android?p=");

        private String packageName;
        private String marketUrl;

        private AppStore(String pName, String url) {
            this.packageName = pName;
            this.marketUrl = url;
        }

        public String getPackageName() {
            return this.packageName;
        }

        public String getMarketUrl() {
            return this.marketUrl;
        }

        public static AppStore getAppStore(String packageName) {
            if(GOOGLE.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageName)) {
                return GOOGLE;
            } else if(AMAZON.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageName)) {
                return AMAZON;
            } 

            return null;
        }
    };

    public static AppStore getAppStore(Context ctx) {
        String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
        PackageManager pacman = ctx.getPackageManager();
        String installer = pacman.getInstallerPackageName(packageName);

        return AppStore.getAppStore(installer);
    }
```

But I am not able to test it. Because I am always getting null from my local build. Is there any way to test whether it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Google let you set up alpha and beta testing groups: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#alpha-beta

The idea being that you publish your app in an "alpha" state, and specify a Google(+) group that has access. They can then download it through the Play store, but normal users won't see it.